# Date request become in NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with my query. I want to show all date from a row but some come in NULL and others comes fine! This is my query, do I need to change something?

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT
    dbo.ItemClass.Description,
    dbo.Item.SubDescription3,
    dbo.ItemClassComponent.Detail1,
    dbo.ItemClassComponent.Detail2,
    dbo.ItemClassComponent.Detail3,
    dbo.ItemDynamic.Cost,
    dbo.ItemDynamic.Price,
    dbo.ItemDynamic.StoreID,
    dbo.ItemDynamic.Quantity,
    dbo.ItemDynamic.LastSold,
    dbo.ItemDynamic.LastReceived
FROM dbo.ItemDynamic
INNER JOIN dbo.ItemClass
    ON dbo.ItemDynamic.ID = dbo.ItemClass.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.Item
    ON dbo.ItemDynamic.ID = dbo.Item.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.ItemClassComponent
    ON dbo.ItemDynamic.ID = dbo.ItemClassComponent.ID
WHERE (dbo.ItemDynamic.LastReceived >= CONVERT(datetime, '2015-03-01 00:00:00', 102))
AND (dbo.ItemDynamic.Quantity >= 1)
```

Comment: Tagged `oracle`? Seems to be `sql server` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add something in your where clause to filter out null values

```
WHERE     
dbo.ItemDynamic.LastReceived IS NOT NULL
AND (dbo.ItemDynamic.LastReceived >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-03-01 00:00:00', 102)) 
AND (dbo.ItemDynamic.Quantity >= 1)
```

UPDATE: since your comment says you wan to include the rows with null dates then your where clause should be more like this:

```
WHERE    
    (dbo.ItemDynamic.Quantity >= 1)
    AND ((dbo.ItemDynamic.LastReceived IS NULL) OR
     (dbo.ItemDynamic.LastReceived >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-03-01 00:00:00', 102)))
```

Comment: Thanks,  but the problem is that i need the all the dates that are in as NULL, in others words there is more than 2k dates in the row but almost all appear as NULL but if i make a simple select from the table everything is fine!. there is any way that i can see what is inside the NULL camp?? thanks

Comment: Thanks Joe, But I think I 'm not explaining well . what I need is that instead of showing me the date field as NULL, the date itself appears, if I do a simple SELECT* without use JOIN, it show me all dates perfect with out NULL but once Join done , most of the fields become in NULL and I need to filter the dates. Thanks